# Removing alert from code forces it to enter infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, alert

I have a piece of code that has a few window alert messages. It works fine. However, if I remove the alert statements, the program enters into an infinite loop. This is weird for me.

Can someone help me identify the problem with the code?

```
function countSwaps(arr) {

    let notVisited = {}, swaps = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        notVisited[i] = true;
    }

    while (Object.keys(notVisited).length) {
        alert("main pass");
        let nextPos, currentPos = Object.keys(notVisited)[0];
        while (arr[currentPos] !== parseInt(currentPos+1)) {
            nextPos = arr[currentPos] - 1;
            [arr[currentPos], arr[nextPos]] = [arr[nextPos], arr[currentPos]];

            swaps+= 1;
            alert("Swap " + arr[currentPos] + " and " + arr[nextPos] + "\n");
            delete notVisited[nextPos];
        }
        delete notVisited[currentPos];
    }
    return swaps;
}
console.log(countSwaps([2,3,4,1,5]));
```

Comment: The inner loop is looping even when the alert is present .

Comment: NB: Never use `alert` for debugging. It changes the timing of the code. Use the debugger and/or `console.log` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it runs an infinite loop for me without the alerts as well.

It seems like the problem is the following expression: `parseInt(currentPos+1)`

The addition happens before the conversion from a string to a number, so for example:

```
currentPos = '4';
currentPos + 1 == '41';
parseInt(currentPos + 1) == 41
```

What you want is probably `parseInt(currentPos) + 1`. Now:

```
currentPos = '4';
parseInt(currentPos) + 1 == 5
```

With this the loop seems to quit and I get the result of 3 swaps out of it.

Answer (score -1):

This is cause of infinite loop.

```
while (Object.keys(notVisited).length)
```

It should be something like

```
while (Object.keys(notVisited).length > 0)
```

That is a property, it will always return true